# Can't create file using vertx

Tags: java, asynchronous, filesystems, vert.x

I have tried to create/write an `AsyncFile` using the following methods,

```
vertx.fileSystem().writeFile("C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/filetwo.txt", buffer, new AsyncResultHandler<Void>{
```

and

```
vertx.fileSystem().open("filetwo.txt", new AsyncResultHandler<AsyncFile>(){
```

Neither method manages to create a new file and I can't figure out why. I have tried different formats for the file, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Could you post more details about how and what kind of Buffer content you are trying to write because plain simple writing a file actually works fine like this:

```
Buffer buffer = Buffer.buffer("This is a Test Text!");
vertx.fileSystem().writeFile("testfile.txt", buffer, 
    new Handler<AsyncResult<Void>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(AsyncResult<Void> result) {
            if(result.succeeded()) {
                container.logger().info("Success!");
            } else {
                container.logger().info("Failed!");
            }
        }
});
```

The testfile is created at the root of the started Module, writing the Buffer Text to it and returning

```
INFO: Success!
```

as it completed successfully.

Also

```
vertx.fileSystem().writeFile(
    "d:/testfile.txt", buffer, 
    new Handler<AsyncResult<Void>>() {
```

works fine with absolute path under windows.

Maybe there is something with the Buffer content or another issue. If you have more insights, maybe we can figure it out.